# Why bing returns a 2 digits number of results from server?

Tags: bing

I run this url in my browser 
`http://www.bing.com/search?q=italy&cc=us&qdr:d`
and I get 260M (million) results.
I run it on my webserver with curl and I get only 28 (literal) results?

What causes this with bing?

Comment: Maybe bings the first 28 results from the first page of the query. While in the web browser it gives those 28 but also counts how many in total

Comment: no, because more specific queries return no values at all from the server which means the pool of the query run by the server is numerically smaller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using yahoo since returns the same results anyway and has no problem on the server.